# Incorrect return type in function overloading without function arguments in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function that can return objects with different values depending on certain conditions. This function doesn't receive any arguments.

I wrote two overloads that describe different return types, but when I use this function and try to destruct values from the object I always receive a value that is defined on the first overload even if it doesn't fit the conditions.

Snippet:

```
const params = {
  brandId: 1, // could be undefined
  productId: 2, // could be undefined
  centerId: 3, // could be undefined
};

type ValidParams = {
  isValid: boolean;
  params: {
    brandId: number;
    productId: number;
    centerId: number;
  };
};

type InvalidParams = {
  isValid: boolean;
  params: {
    brandId: undefined;
    productId: undefined;
    centerId: undefined;
  };
};

export function useParams(): ValidParams;
export function useParams(): InvalidParams;

export function useParams() {
  const { brandId, productId, centerId } = params;

  if (brandId && productId && centerId) {
    return {
      isValid: true,
      params: {
        brandId,
        productId,
        centerId,
      },
    };
  } else {
    return {
      isValid: false,
      params: {
        brandId: undefined,
        productId: undefined,
        centerId: undefined,
      },
    };
  }
}

function someFunction() {
  const {
    isValid,
    params: { brandId, productId, centerId },
  } = useParams();

  if (isValid) {
    const id = brandId;
  }
}
```

I expect that if `isValid` value is true, then all of the params are numbers, and in case that `isValid` is false, then params are undefined.

e.g:

```
if (isValid) {
  brandId, productId, centerId // all are numbers
}
```

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

TS version: 4.6.3

Much appreciate any help on this)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `params` object as an argument to useParams function. So that you have some parameters to overload.

Also make `isValid` a literal type for both the interfaces

Something like this:

```
const params = {
  brandId: undefined, // could be undefined
  productId: undefined, // could be undefined
  centerId: undefined, // could be undefined
};

type ValidParams = {
  isValid: true;
  params: {
    brandId: number;
    productId: number;
    centerId: number;
  };
};

type InvalidParams = {
  isValid: false;
  params: {
    brandId: undefined;
    productId: undefined;
    centerId: undefined;
  };
};

// accept params as an argument so that you have some parameters to overload
export function useParams(_params: {
  brandId: undefined;
  productId: undefined;
  centerId: undefined;
}): InvalidParams;
export function useParams(_params: {
  brandId: number;
  productId: number;
  centerId: number;
}): ValidParams;
export function useParams(_params: {
  brandId: number | undefined;
  productId: number | undefined;
  centerId: number | undefined;
}) {
  const { brandId, productId, centerId } = _params;

  if (brandId && productId && centerId) {
    return {
      isValid: true,
      params: {
        brandId,
        productId,
        centerId,
      },
    };
  } else {
    return {
      isValid: false,
      params: {
        brandId: undefined,
        productId: undefined,
        centerId: undefined,
      },
    };
  }
}

const {
  isValid,
  params: { brandId, productId, centerId },
} = useParams(params); // pass params as an argument

if (isValid && brandId && productId && centerId) {
  const id: number = brandId;
}
```

In this case, I believe you do not need the `isValid` flag, so you can remove it as follows.

```
const params = {
  brandId: 1, // could be 1
  productId: 1, // could be 1
  centerId: 1, // could be 1
};

type ValidParams = {
  params: {
    brandId: number;
    productId: number;
    centerId: number;
  };
};

type InvalidParams = {
  params: {
    brandId: undefined;
    productId: undefined;
    centerId: undefined;
  };
};

// accept params as an argument so that you have some parameters to overload
export function useParams(_params: {
  brandId: undefined;
  productId: undefined;
  centerId: undefined;
}): InvalidParams;
export function useParams(_params: {
  brandId: number;
  productId: number;
  centerId: number;
}): ValidParams;
export function useParams(_params: {
  brandId: number | undefined;
  productId: number | undefined;
  centerId: number | undefined;
}) {
  const { brandId, productId, centerId } = _params;

  if (brandId && productId && centerId) {
    return {
      params: {
        brandId,
        productId,
        centerId,
      },
    };
  } else {
    return {
      params: {
        brandId: undefined,
        productId: undefined,
        centerId: undefined,
      },
    };
  }
}

const {
  params: { brandId, productId, centerId },
} = useParams(params); // pass params as an argument

if (brandId && productId && centerId) {
  const id: number = brandId;
}
```

It's still a valid code. If you pass `{brandId: 1, productId: 1, centerId: 1}` as an argument to `useParams`, you will get `brandId && productId && centerId` as `true` because overload will infer all as a `number` type. and same for `undefined` type.

This is still a valid code. If you pass `{brandId: 1, productId: 1, centerId: 1}` as arguments to `useParams`, you will get `brandId && productId && centerId` as `true` since overflow infers each as a 'number' type. The same applies to `undefined` types.

Comment: Thank you for the option! Unfortunately, I took `param` from hook and they can not be passed through functions params

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to handle this is to define your return types a little differently as well as indicate that the function can return one or the other with a [Discriminated Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

In this code, you *need* to test for `isValid` being `true` before the compiler will let you access the values. I've also tweaked the test to check explicitly for `undefined` as a `0` value would also be "not there". You can keep the "truthy number" check if `0` is not a valid value, but you explicitly call out that it could be undefined without indicating that `0` is also not valid.

```
const params = {
  brandId: 1, // could be undefined
  productId: 2, // could be undefined
  centerId: undefined, // could be undefined
};

type ValidParams = {
  isValid: true;
  params: {
    brandId: number;
    productId: number;
    centerId: number;
  };
};

type InvalidParams = {
  isValid: false;
};

function useParams(): ValidParams | InvalidParams {
  const { brandId, productId, centerId } = params;

  if (brandId != undefined && productId != undefined && centerId != undefined) {
    return {
      isValid: true,
      params: {
        brandId,
        productId,
        centerId,
      },
    };
  } else {
    return {
      isValid: false,
    };
  }
}

function someFunction() {
  // cannot destructure the params here, because we don't
  // know yet if it is valid or invalid type
  const p = useParams();
  if (p.isValid) {
    // we know now we have the params values,
    // so we can access, destructure, etc.
    const id = p.params.brandId;
  }
  console.dir(p);
}

someFunction();
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgQwE4ILYRgXhgbwFAwwBGKYAJgJJkBcMAjADQwD0zMoArgDZnECmMDuT4AzAJZg+ZAvCQgyHYFCq0ATE1bsQ3XkQFCyoiVJnA+YKHyQrBw8ZLIa2nHv1uH7JgL4BuPHigATzgBADUELjEyAAVkNAxsfEIxCHDImhgoJA4+P0JEFHRaJMJiUkoMsA5UPSQ80rg5BSUbKpqresIzCytW6tr63zwhgOCBCjAANwio2MKE3BkUtKjaEQiIXOG-PBEhJTFwQU25+IAKAEpaFZi49BgAHxgJ6fTT+5LQSFgcMoRyKhMRryRTKRzscyWay8LxYeB3CA7ZIiGBnEj-CowACE2AMRgcMAAZITZCCWrwce58VIiSTulCqNjcXZjGQLotSjAkHwoBwkGAOZyYMsZhksjkGDJOQV4sUpUL0QDHPLpU1QYCVaV6b1lUKYF5JZyhoRYXwuJtBYRubz+ZbSiL0msNnxDaVjfrhv49mADkcICBUHwAGL7KCHMCXQVfaDwOEcE4Iy71MQos5wAB0Dqi7JKXXAMaicIzMvQ6cVFUGpnzIC4fHTZDESDTFz8Xn8-sDIZ9YfASaAA)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This works, but unfortunately when I tried to destruct these fields `brandId` is still `number | undefined`. It was announced "Control Flow Analysis for Destructured Discriminated Unions" on TS 4.6, so I hoped it would work...

Anyway thank you so much!

Comment: @OrestBats If you look at the code I have, you *test first* then destruct the fields when the compiler knows they exits. I've done it this way to prevent the access to those fields when invalid (you *may* have needs where that does not work, but then you really don't need to handle the types differently or even have a bool `isValid`).